# Ionic mapbox error

Tags: ionic-framework, mapbox

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot set property 'map' of undefined

Can anyone help me with this?

My code is below:

```
map: mapboxgl.Map;
    ionViewWillEnter() 
    {   
    mapboxgl.accesstoken=...
    function loadMap(lng,lat) {
        this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
        center: [lng, lat],
        zoom: 10,
        pitch: 80,
        minZoom: 3,
        maxZoom: 17,
        container: 'map'
      });....}
```

Comment: On which particular line?

Comment: this.map = new mapboxgl.Map....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by declaring first a variable that to this and referencing that then

Comment: Instead of using this you declare that = this. So line 6 would be that.map